# Countdown timer - Getting bad read from variable

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, concurrency, thread-safety

I have created a simple GameTimer class which countsdown from a given number, a Swing GUI containing an updateTimer() method which updates the timer component on the EDT, and a RunTimer class which continuously invokes updateTimer() until the GameTimer is stopped.

The first instance of the timer always runs fine, but once stopped and another timer is created and started, the new timer sometimes flickers between the current countdown and the value the last timer was stopped at.

Moving the component updates to the EDT doesn't seem to have worked.

Invoking updateTimer() after the timer's last revolution to ensure the last value is updated hasn't worked.

Making the 'secondsLeft' variable static solves the problem however this means I cant use multiple instances of GameTimer simultaneously to time different events.

I have added the output that prints out the variable values when I start the countdown timer from 20, stop it at 17, which then creates and starts a new countdown Timer.

Baffled, please help!

```
  public class GameTimer implements Runnable {

    private int secondsLeft; 
    private boolean timerStop; 
    /**
    * Creates a timer with a given number of seconds on the clock.
    */
    public GameTimer(int seconds)
    {     
    secondsLeft = seconds;
    timerStop = false; // Set to true when timer should stop
    }

    /**
    * Stops timer permanently 
    */
    public void stopTimer()
    {
     timerStop = true;
    }

    public int getSecondsLeft()
    {
     return secondsLeft;   
    }         

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
     // While there timer is still counting down or all players finish 
     // their actions.
      while (!timerStop)
      {
        //TEST  
        System.out.println("GamerTimer before sleep reads: " +             String.valueOf(secondsLeft));  

        // Wait 1 second  
        try
        {
         Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
         System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
        }  

        //decrement timer 1 second
        secondsLeft--;

        if (secondsLeft <= 0)
        {
          timerStop = true;
        }    

        //TEST - COMMENT OUT AFTER TESTING
        System.out.println("GamerTimer after sleep reads: " + String.valueOf(secondsLeft));
      }     
    }
}



    private void updateTimer(final int secondsLeft)
    {
      timePanel.setVisible(true);

      try
      {     
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){      

         @Override
         public void run() 
         {    
            //TEST VALUES - COMMENT OUT AFTER TESTING   
            //System.out.println(String.valueOf(SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()));
            timeTextField.setText(String.valueOf(secondsLeft));

            if (secondsLeft <= 5)
            {
              timeTextField.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            }
            else
            {   
              timeTextField.setBackground(Color.white);
            }
           }
         });
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());   
      }    
    }    




     public class RunTimer implements Runnable
    {  

     private GameTimer t;    

     public RunTimer(final GameTimer timer)
     {
       t = timer;  
     }        

     @Override
     public void run()
     {      
       stopTimer = false;

       while (!stopTimer)
       {    
         //TEST VALUES - COMMENT OUT AFTER TESTING  
         System.out.println("RunTimer class reads: " + String.valueOf(t.getSecondsLeft()));

         updateTimer(t.getSecondsLeft());
         try
         {
          Thread.sleep(500);
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
          System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
         }
       }

       timePanel.setVisible(false);
     }
    }



    **Output Results:**
    GamerTimer before sleep reads: 20
    RunTimer class reads: 20
    RunTimer class reads: 20
    GamerTimer after sleep reads: 19
    GamerTimer before sleep reads: 19
    RunTimer class reads: 19
    RunTimer class reads: 19
    GamerTimer after sleep reads: 18
    GamerTimer before sleep reads: 18
    RunTimer class reads: 18
    RunTimer class reads: 18
    GamerTimer after sleep reads: 17
    GamerTimer before sleep reads: 17
    RunTimer class reads: 17
    GamerTimer before sleep reads: 20
    RunTimer class reads: 20
    RunTimer class reads: 17
    RunTimer class reads: 20
    GamerTimer after sleep reads: 16
    RunTimer class reads: 16
    GamerTimer after sleep reads: 19
    GamerTimer before sleep reads: 19
    RunTimer class reads: 19
    RunTimer class reads: 16
    RunTimer class reads: 19
    RunTimer class reads: 16
    GamerTimer after sleep reads: 18
    GamerTimer before sleep reads: 18
    RunTimer class reads: 18
    RunTimer class reads: 16
    RunTimer class reads: 18
    RunTimer class reads: 16
    GamerTimer after sleep reads: 17
    GamerTimer before sleep reads: 17
    RunTimer class reads: 17
    RunTimer class reads: 16
    RunTimer class reads: 17
    RunTimer class reads: 16
    BUILD STOPPED (total time: 11 seconds)
```

Comment: Sounds like you still have multiple `GameTimer`s (or `UpdateTimer`s) running

Comment: There's actually no real need for the `GameTimer`, it really needs to do is calculate the difference between when it was started and now, it doesn't need a loop...

Comment: How do you start your `GameTimer`? Do you have an instance of GameTimer for each GameTimer/Thread or are you maybe creating multiple Threads out of one `GameTimer` by `new Thread(gametimer)`?

Comment: There is possibly some cross-over where 2 timers are running simultaneously but they are separate instances each with their own 'secondsLeft' variable, so why would this cause a problem. Ultimately, Im hoping to have a few different timers running for different activities.

Comment: MadProgrammer, my GUI shows a timer counting down from 20 so think the loop is necessary.

Comment: GameTimer timer = new Clock.GameTimer(20);
Thread t = new Thread(timer);
t.start();

Comment: try to print the Thread.currentThread() as well in the sout

Comment: Very useful tip hunter, thankyou! After doing this I found that as the 2 timers were run so close together, the stopTimer variable was being switched back to false so fast that the original RunTimer was never exiting its while loop. My solution was to move the stopTimer variable to the RunTimer class so each RunTimer has its own stopTimer variable. Thanks for helping me solve this, and giving me a great debugging tip!